# Different indentation

Tags: indentation

I'm writing a thesis and I'm having this issue: different files have different indentation.
I'm quite new on Latex and it won't be a surprise if I have some useless packages or I did a stupid mistake.
That's my main.tex file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12]{report}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfiles} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-ibid,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{biblio.bib}
    
    \AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\footnotesize}
    
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*0.5}
    \titlespacing{\subsection}{10pt}{*2}{*0.5}
    \titlespacing{\subsubsection}{20pt}{*0}{*0}
    
    \geometry{a4paper, top=2 cm, bottom=2 cm, left=3 cm, right=2 cm}
    \graphicspath{{images/}}
    
    \title{Blockchain for good}
    \author{Giovanni Zago}

    \doublespacing
    
    \begin{document}

    \chapter*{Introduzione}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{L'azienda}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Il progetto}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Aspetti etici}
    \subfile{sections/01.Introduzione}
    
    \chapter{Nozioni di base}
    \subfile{sections/02.Capitolo1}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=Fonti]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,keyword=libro,title=Bibliografia]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,keyword=articolo,title=Articoli]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,keyword=online,title=Sitografia]
    \end{document}
```

Subfile 01.Introduzione has the indentation i like: few pt every paragraph. 02.Capitolo1, instead, has indentation only in the very first line.
01.Introduzione and 02.Capitolo1 both looks like this

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{\subfix{../images/}}}

\author{Giovanni Zago}
\title{Nozioni di base}

\begin{document}
%some text
\end{documenti}
```

and they are both divided in section, subsection etc.

Any idea?

EDIT:
Thats how id like all the document to be indented (snap from 01.Introduzione)
[image: 1]

And thats how 02.Capitolo1 is (not) indeted
[image: 2]

I alsdo tried to post the code the most compliant i could

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!  I am not sure than anyone here is going to be able to answer you question in this form.  Please can you review [this introduction](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and try to write a question that follows the guidelines?

Comment: we can not run your code and you have not shown your output so it is impossible to guess what your problem is. What is indented diffrently??, at least show an image (upload it but remove the `!` from the generated markdown, until you have enough points to allow inline image posts.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,12]{report}` report does not have an option `12` (latex will have warned about that) You probably intended `12pt`

Comment: Note that by default the first paragraph of each section is not indented, just later paragraphs indent the first line. Is that your question?